# Export and Import Taxonomies and Extra Fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

I created extra field in Login Form, I Installed even Extra Module ([address](https://www.drupal.org/node/2607696)) and create Taxonomies

Now I want to Export these configurations to another Drupal. This Drupal is the Clone of the main Drupal.

I Tried to use import/export Configuration (admin/config/development) But I have several error during import ( shortcut and error Ajax 500 )

I don't have active and staging folder ([link](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/08/27/understanding-configuration-management-in-drupal-8/))

Is it correct to use Conguration Management to export Module and Taxonomies?

Comment: Some ideas: 1) make sure Address is installed on cloned site; 2) try drush config sync instead of the UI; 3) if you're trying to move parts of the configuration instead of the whole of the site's configuration, maybe you have a dependency problem, i.e. the config you're trying to import may depend on some other config you have not yet imported.

Comment: @Jonathan After few hours I have this Error now ( via Cli )
`drush config-import deploy -y` in deploy I have all my configurations
my error is: `Entities exist of type <em class="placeholder">Shortcut link</em> and <em class="placeholder"></em> <em class="placeholder">Default</em>. These entities need to be deleted before importing.`
My drush version is 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

According to this [drupal link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2638392)

```
drush ev '\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage("shortcut_set")->load("default")->delete();'
```